# How would I conditionally append data to an existing dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to conditionally append data to an existing template dataframe? I'll try to make the data below as simple as possible, since I'm asking more for conceptual help than actual code so I better understand the mindset of solving these kinds of problems in the future (but actual code would be great too).

#### Example Data

I have a dataframe below that shows 4 dummy products SKUs that a client may order. These SKUs never change. Sometimes a client orders large quantities of each SKU, and sometimes they only order one or two SKUs. Due to reporting, I need to fill unordered SKUs with zeroes (probably use `ffill`?)

**Dummy dataframe** `DF`

| product_sku | quantity | total_cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 |  |  |
| 5678 |  |  |
| 4321 |  |  |
| 2468 |  |  |

#### Problem

Currently, my data only returns the SKUs that customers have ordered **(a)**, but I would like unordered SKUs to be returned, with zeros filled in for `quantity` and `total_cost` **(b)**

**(a)**

| product_sku | quantity | total_cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 10 | 50.00 |
| 5678 | 3 | 75.00 |

**(b)**

| product_sku | quantity | total_cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 10 | 50.00 |
| 5678 | 3 | 75.00 |
| 4321 | 0 | 0 |
| 2468 | 0 | 0 |

I'm wondering if there's a way to take that existing dataframe, and simply append any sales that actually occurred, leaving the unordered SKUs as zero or blank (whatever makes more sense).

I just need some help thinking through the steps logically, and wasn't able to find anything like this. I'm still relatively novice at this stuff, so let me know if I'm missing any pertinent information.

Thanks!

Comment: do you know the SKUs upfront, or need to support dynamic new SKUs?

Comment: Some questions: How do you know the price of a SKU, is that stored in another dataframe? Do you want to update the quantity when one sale is made, or once every now and then? And do you want the total cost to be updated once the quantity changes or can it be calculated once you need it?

Comment: @LiorCohen the SKUs never change, and no new ones will be added. Thanks for the clarifying question!

Comment: do you have all the customers in the same dataframe, so a column with customer ID as well or a dataframe per customer?

Comment: @Ben.T Different DF for each customer. There are only about 10 customers, and no new ones will be added. Kind of a what you see is what you get thing, where all that data is really all we use.

Answer (score 1):

one way is to use `reindex` after putting the column with product's names as index with `set_index`. With your notation it would be something like

```
l_products = DF['product_sku'].tolist() #you may have the list differently

b = (a.set_index('product_sku')
      .reindex(l_products, fill_value=0)
      .reset_index()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the SKus a-priori, maintain one `DataFrame` initizlized with zeros and update the relevant rows. Then you will always have all SKUs.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

# initialization
df = pd.DataFrame(0, index = ['1234', '5678', '4321', '2468'], 
                     columns={'quantity', 'total_cost'})
print(df)

# updating
df.loc['1234', :] = {'total_cost': 100, 'quantity': 4}
print(df)

# incrementing quantity
df.loc['1234', 'quantity'] += 5
print(df)


      total_cost  quantity
1234           0         0
5678           0         0
4321           0         0
2468           0         0

      total_cost  quantity
1234         100         4
5678           0         0
4321           0         0
2468           0         0

      total_cost  quantity
1234         100         9
5678           0         0
4321           0         0
2468           0         0
```